Ubuntu 24.04 LTS cant print with canon pixma mg2540s
once connected via usb , printer was added but unfortunately when i launch a print i get notified that print job is successful but nothing is printed.
I recently switched from windows to linux pls help.
Thank You

First, install some dependencies:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcups2t64

The closest drivers I could find were for the MG2500 series as the MG2500s series didn't show any linux drivers.
Scroll halfway down the linked page. Select Linux as the operating system and then you should see 2 results on the page for Debian packages. One for the printer and one for the scanner. Download each of these and then transfer these downloaded files into your user's Home folder.
Extract each file and then cd into the extracted directory, for example:
cd ~/cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb

and then run the install.sh file:
./install.sh

if you get a permission denied error, then use sudo to run the file:
sudo ./install.sh

Do the same for your scanner driver:
cd ~/scangearmp-mg2500series-2.20-1-deb
./install.sh

and again, if you get a permission denied error, then run the command using sudo instead:
sudo ./install.sh

When installing these packages, it should walk you though the basics if needed, like maybe setting up a name for the printer.
Probably reboot after installation just for good measure and then try to print something.

it worked , and printing was done
thanks
